# Check UISwitch status on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I am having problem with status of `UISwitch` at start. Why is my `switch` always in the `on` state?

```
@IBOutlet  weak var switch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let sw = switch {
        if sw.on  {
            print("on")
        } else {
            print("off")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set it in your storyboard?

Comment: why are you if let-ing a force unwrapped optional?

Comment: @AndréMuniz what do u mean by set in storyboard? its state in storyboard is ON.

Answer (score 1):

The switch will be whatever you set it in the storyboard / interface builder. If you set it to on in the storyboard, it will always be on when the app first loads, and vice versa for setting it to off.

If you want to set it to off when your view first loads (programatically), regardless of what is set in the storyboard, use `switch.on = false`

If you want the switch's state to be saved when the app is closed, you should look into using NSUserDefaults ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/))

Here is a screenshot of the state set in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I was making some experiments, found out if u put in viewWillAppear it will work fine as I want. Not sure why...